# Repairing VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net

I throw in huge troubles with recreating a multproject solution into a single project solution where my program become unusable.

I have all code files saved and problem is with showing designer in IDE and errors connecting with that.

Situation:
All forms are subclassed with class called cls_transform which make form transparent while moving.

```
Public Class cls_transform
       Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Private _OpacityMove As Double = 0.5
Private _OpacityOriginal As Double = 1
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Long = &HA1
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Long = &HA0
Private Const WM_MOVING As Long = &H216
Private Const WM_SIZE As Long = &H5

Private Sub cls_transform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Static LButtonDown As Boolean

    If CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN Then
        LButtonDown = True
    ElseIf CLng(m.Msg) = WM_NCLBUTTONUP Then
        LButtonDown = False
    End If

    If LButtonDown Then
        If CLng(m.Msg) = WM_MOVING Then
            If Me.Opacity <> _OpacityMove Then
                _OpacityOriginal = Me.Opacity
                Me.Opacity = _OpacityMove
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf Not LButtonDown Then
        If Me.Opacity <> _OpacityOriginal Then Me.Opacity = _OpacityOriginal
    End If
    MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
End Sub

Public Property OpacityMove() As Double
    Get
        Return _OpacityMove
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Double)
        _OpacityMove = Value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
    Me.Name = "cls_transform"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
End Sub
End Class
```

This is how code of one empty form "frm_myForm" look like:

```
Public Class frm_myForm
       Inherits cls_transform

Private Sub frm_myForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

And this is Designer code of that form:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frm_myForm
        Inherits cls_transform

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'frm_myForm
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
    Me.Name = "frm_myForm"
    Me.Text = "frm_myForm"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
End Class
```

When I try to "View Designer" from IDE instead of to see a form I get white screen with error:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: frm_myForm --- The base class 'noviprog.cls_transform' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

That happen with all forms which inherits from cls_transform.

When cls_transform was in separate library (separate project of same solution)  which was referenced to actual project that works.

Is it possible to get this working when code files and that class would be in same project and how to get this working?

Comment: From your code, there shouldn't be any problem. Can you please explain the file structure you are using? (are all the classes written in the same file? if not in which files?)

Comment: In this case this class are in separate file called cls_transform.vb which is in same project with other files. I am trying to recreate workable project by involving files from old solution to new solution - one by one.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem either as far as you have added the given file correctly. Example: in the "Solution Explorer", right-click on the Project name, "Add", "Existing Item" (or "New Item" and write all the contents there).

Comment: I do such. File by file. I have very strange and unexplainable happenings with IDE this days so maybe I need to reinstall VB/VS?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with unexplainable things but if you open a new project, write the code referring to the main form as you posted it, put all the cls_transform related code in another file (and add it to the project rightly), there shouldn't be any problem. If you find problems, you might have to look at the Visual Studio/your computer .

Comment: Last days several things happening which don't work for me what other people say "it should work". So, thanks for inspecting and referring to my code. Is it good idea to move from VS2008 to VS2010 at same time?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you rightly. Moving a 2008 project to 2010 shouldn't, in principle, give any problem and you might do that (somehow recommendable; not strongly recommendable). Having different VS versions installed on your computer (2008 and 2010) is not a problem at all. On my computer, I have 3 different VS versions and haven't ever had an issue.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try to do such too.